# CSS doesn't want to be uploaded from another controller

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, frameworks

I have some headers and footers that have `CSS` in them, and when I load the view in a controller, the `CSS` displays just fine.

However, when I use another controller to load the same view, the `CSS` does not show up.

Why does the `CSS` file not get displayed when I call it later in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

```
   public function __construct()
   {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->view("css_file");
   }
```

Put that function at the top of your controller file. It will load the `CSS` for all methods. That way, you never have to explicitly load the CSS, it will always be there!

Alternatively, you may want to consider a templating library like [Ocular](https://github.com/lonnieezell/Ocular-Template-Library). It makes it so you can load headers and footers (and whatever else, like style, JS, etc) in one single command.

A templating library will make your life so easy, you won't know how you got a long without one.